# Angular (change) event not firing on all changes

Tags: angular, events

I have an Angular 7 app that contains a text input. The value of the text input is bound to a component level variable `accountNumber`.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="accountNumber" (change)="isAccountNumberFlagged(accountNumber)" />
```

I have a component method `isAccountNumberFlagged(number: string)` that checks to see if the `accountNumber` is flagged and if it is display a warning (by making a specific  element visible. I have this method bound to the `change event` and it works as expected.

What doesn't work as expected is when I change the value in the text input after having entered a value that has been "flagged" and tab to another control. The `(change)` event does not fire in these cases.

**Sequence of events**

1. Component loads
2. Change the value in the text input = `(change)` event fires
3. Enter a flagged account number = `(change)` event fires and flagged warning displays
4. Change the value in the text input = `(change)` DOES NOT fire (even if I enter another or the same flagged account number)

Clearly I am missing something about how the `(change)` event works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21):

You can choose 2 methods for this:

Have created a **[Stackblitx Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-input-binding)** for your reference

**1.) Try to use `(input)` event handler instead.**

```
<input type="text" 
       [(ngModel)]="accountNumber" 
       (input)="isAccountNumberFlagged(accountNumber)" />
```

**2.) OR Separate your NgModel Input and Event Handlers**

```
<input type="text" 
       [ngModel]="accountNumber"      // [] Input Binding
       (ngModelChange)="isAccountNumberFlagged($event)" /> // () Event Binding

// Be sure to update your accountNumber value inside the function
// to reflect such changes
isAccountNumberFlagged(accountNumber) {
   ...
   this.accountNumber = newValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why does the `isAccountNumberFlagged` method need to set the new value of `this.accountNumber`? Since the event is `ngModelChange` doesn't Angular know the new value already?

Comment: Hi, this is because when we use [(ngModel)] where Input and Event binding are as one, every time you change the value of your input, it will also update at the same time but if we were to separate the Input and Event Binding, implementing [ngModel] and (ngModelChange), the angular doesn't know the new value being input as we have separated the Event Binding thus the angular gives us the liberty to assign your custom value to your designated [ngModel] variable inside the (ngModelChange) event function. Hope this answers your inquiry :)